# Pagination not showing up

Tags: pagination

I have included pagination on a series of pages.  From within the CP when I click the View Rendor button from within the template, all looks great.  However, when I link to a page with the pagination control from some place else in my site, the pagination control does not show.  Any ideas as to why?  Here is a image showing my template code:
[image: code snip]

Thank you for any help - Kim

Answer (score 1):

Pagination only shows if you need it, and works by limiting the number of entries displayed by an EE tag.  Your channel entries tag limits the output to a single entry (`limit="1"`), so for this page pagination will never be needed - and so will never show.  I'm guessing that the Template render button simply constructs the page without processing the content (and so ignores the limit="1" parameter - and so shows the pagination content there.

So, try changing the limit to a higher number...

HTH